# Pandas redundant multi-indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

I've written some functions to help aggregate data. In the end, they give me what I want, but with a crazy multi-indexed series:

```
fec988a2-6eba-49e0-8327-a89f25143ccf  fec988a2-6eba-49e0-8327-a89f25143ccf  com.facebook.katana                  fec988a2-6eba-49e0-8327-a89f25143ccf    1067
                                                                            com.android.systemui                 fec988a2-6eba-49e0-8327-a89f25143ccf     935
                                                                            com.facebook.orca                    fec988a2-6eba-49e0-8327-a89f25143ccf     893
                                                                            com.android.chrome                   fec988a2-6eba-49e0-8327-a89f25143ccf     739
                                                                            com.whatsapp                         fec988a2-6eba-49e0-8327-a89f25143ccf     515
```

I only need the first index, and the one with the app names (and the value of course). How do I get rid of unwanted indices like this?

Comment: Do you think `df = df.reset_index(level=[0,1]).reset_index()` ?

Comment: IIUC you have a multi index, then you can use the function `droplevel`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html for the documentation.

Comment: @jezrael: "ValueError: cannot insert id, already exists"

Comment: @Inkidu616 - then use `df = df.reset_index(level=[0,1]).rename_axis(['a','b']).reset_index()`. Btw, what code is used for these problem? Maybe solution should be change this code.

Comment: @jezrael: Same problem (the first reset_index is what causes it). I inadvertently created the redundant indices by using this line: `df.groupby(['id', 'application'])['id'].value_counts().groupby(['id']).nlargest(top)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - first remove unnecessary levels (here only `2`, because `group_keys=False` in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) remove another) and second with `name='new'` for convert `Series` to `DataFrame` with set new column name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'application':list('abbddedcc'),
                   'id':list('aaabbbbbb')})

print (df)
  application id
0           a  a
1           b  a
2           b  a
3           d  b
4           d  b
5           e  b
6           d  b
7           c  b
8           c  b
```

---

```
top = 2
df1 = (df.groupby(['id', 'application'])['id']
        .value_counts()
        .groupby(['id'], group_keys=False)
        .nlargest(top)
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='new'))
print (df1)
  id application  new
0  a           b    2
1  a           a    1
2  b           d    3
3  b           c    2
```

Or remove `id` from first `groupby`, rather test if same output with real data:

```
top = 2
df1 = (df.groupby(['application'])['id']
        .value_counts()
        .groupby(['id'], group_keys=False)
        .nlargest(top)
        .reset_index(name='new'))
print (df1)
  application id  new
0           b  a    2
1           a  a    1
2           d  b    3
3           c  b    2
```

Comment: Can do `reset_index` in a `while len(df.index) > 1` ?

Comment: @GhasemNaddaf - It depends what need ;) Obviously yes, if want convert `MultiIndex` to columns. If want convert `index` to column is possible use `.reset_index()` with default `Index`, e.g. test it with `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','a','a'],'B': list(range(3))})` and `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: Sweet, totally helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use pd.DataFrame.reset_index() or pd.Series.reset_index() with drop=True argument:

```
n = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx0': [0] * n, 'idx1': range(n, 0, -1), 
                   'idx2': range(0, n), 'idx3': ['a'] * n,
                    'value': [i/2 for i in range(n)]},
                  ).set_index(['idx0', 'idx1', 'idx2',  'idx3'])

df
Out:                     
idx0    idx1    idx2    idx3  value
0       5       0       a     0.0
        4       1       a     0.5
        3       2       a     1.0
        2       3       a     1.5
        1       4       a     2.0 

df.reset_index(level=(1, 3), drop=True)

Out:          
idx0    idx2    value
0       0       0.0
        1       0.5
        2       1.0
        3       1.5
        4       2.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem was that some indices had the same name (id), so I got an error trying to drop all but one of them. Solved by adding the 'group_keys=False' parameter to the groupby function, as @jezrael pointed out.